# Python code in simulate mode

Tags: python

I have a python code that reads output from command line:

```
import subprocess

def get_prg_output():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return out

print get_prg_output()
```

In my office I want to simulate result in this mode:

```
def get_prg_output():
    return 'ok - program executed'

print get_prg_output()
```

Is there an elegant way to do this without comment out the original function?

I've try this:

```
import subprocess

debug = True

if not debug:
    def get_prg_output():
        p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        return out
else:
    def get_prg_output():
        return 'ok - program executed'
print get_prg_output()
```

but I don't like it.

Thanks

Comment: What don't you like about your attempt?

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something like this:

```
def _get_prg_output_real():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return out

def _get_prg_output_fake():
    return 'ok - program executed'
```

Here you can toggle between:

```
get_prg_output = _get_prg_output_fake
```

or

```
get_prg_output = _get_prg_output_real
```

based on user input, or commandline arguments or config files or commenting/uncommenting a single line of code ...

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_prg_output_fake():
    return 'ok - program executed'
```

then, if you want to enable this simulation, just do

```
get_prg_output=get_prg_output_fake
```

Comment: It's a little freakish how we both posted simultaneously and named the fake function almost the same thing ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an environment variable (or a command switch) to control it myself so you don't have to make code changes to test.

```
import os
import subprocess

def _get_prg_output_real():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return out

def _get_prg_output_fake():
    return 'ok - program executed'

if os.environ.get('DEBUG').lower() == 'true':
    get_prg_output = _get_prg_output_fake
else:
    get_prg_output = get_prg_output_real
```